# How to trigger JS event only for the non-hidden media query class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, event-handling, dom-events

I have few input html tags with same class name for mobile and desktop (**media query**)

Sometimes `$(".className").val()` is empty since it is taking value from the hidden html tag.

`$(".className").val()`  should only fetch value from the non hidden  html tag.

Html -

```
  <div class="mobileDiv">
    <input type="text" class="searchItem">
    <input type="text" class="searchCategory">
  </div>

  <div class="desktopDiv">
    <input type="text" class="searchItem">
    <input type="text" class="searchCategory">
  </div>
```

Javascript -

```
// Same code is shared for both mobile and desktop

$(document).on('keyup', '.searchItem', function() {
  val = $(".searchItem").val() 
  categoryVal = $(".searchCategory")

  // cannot use "this" because other class values are also needed on this event
});
```

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `$(".searchItem").val()` will always return the value of the first one found in the page.

Within the event handler function `this` is the element the event actually occurred on

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.searchItem', function() {
  let val = $(this).val() 
  console.log(val)
});
```

```css
input.mobileDiv{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="searchItem mobileDiv">

<input type="text" class="searchItem desktopDiv">
```

Comment: Okay `this` will only fetch value for the `searchItem` class. What if i want to fetch other class values on `searchItem` event?

Comment: Like what? You need to be more specific as nothing like that was mentioned in the question

Comment: I modified the question little bit. Could you please look into it?

Comment: You could include the `:visible` selector

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `$('. className:visible').val()`  It works. Please modify your answer so i can accept your answer :)

Comment: You changed the question after I answered it. Current answer supports what you originally asked. You really shouldn't change the question after answers are posted